# Table Sorting (Using ng-repeat and removing repeat column name using ng-if)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have some data in a table using ng-repeat that is sorted fine. Please see the first fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10201/

```
<tr ng-repeat="each in list | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
```

I'm trying to find a way to have the first column (Name), not repeat the name if the following row has the same name. See the second fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10204/

```
<td ng-show="list[$index].name != list[$index-1].name">{{each.name}}</td>
```

This works initially until the columns are sorted. If you click on the headers, the columns will sort, but the data isn't correct. I know this is due to me using list for the $index. I'm not sure if there's a way to use something else instead? Or I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this to be honest.

Please let me know if more information is required. Thanks! T

Comment: I found this link: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/08/tip-accessing-filtered-array-outside-ng-repeat/

I haven't tested it personally, but if it's accurate, I think you can try something like: "each in sortedlist = (list | orderBy:predicate)"   afterwards, instead of list[$index], use sortedlist[$index].name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `$index` changes when you sort the item and repeated item might not be any more previous or next one (as ensured by logic `list[$index].name != list[$index-1].name`). You can use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to set up/alias the initial index of the ng-repeat, since ng-inited values are not watched they will not change with sorting.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="each in list | orderBy:predicate:reverse" ng-init="index= $index">
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zL14zahn/)**

From documentation

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.